# Extending a list of list with single elements of a list Error

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I was trying to extend a list of list to add an element at the beginning, which is a number:

```
groups = list([list([a, b, c]),list([a2, b2, c2])])
numbers = list([1,2])
```

The result should be looking like this:

```
result = [[1,a, b, c],[2,a2, b2, c2]]
```

This is my code so far:

```
result = []
for i in groups :
    for j in numbers:
        result.append([j,i])
```

Do you have any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong? or a hint on how to solve the issue?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Side note: `list([a2, b2, c2])` is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are using two separate `for` loops, when you really want to iterate over both lists at the same time. For these cases [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) comes handy. It allows you to aggregate multiple iterables. So you could instead do:

```
result = []
for i,j in zip(numbers, groups):
    result.append([i]+j)

print(result)
# [[1, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [2, 'a2', 'b2', 'c2']]
```

---

For a more concise solution you could use a list comprehesion to add the elements from both lists (note that the elements in `numbers` have to be turned to lists):

```
[[i]+j for i,j in zip(numbers, groups)]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [2, 'a2', 'b2', 'c2']]
```